# Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: i18n is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-i18n

I am trying to do a multi-language site with Vue.js, but I don't know how to call the const `i18n` or how to refer to it. I already tried the `eventBus` option, but I think this is not the right choice. I'm using `vue-router`.

**Navbar.vue**

```html
<template>
    <a v-on:click="changeLocale">EN</a>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
        methods: {
            changeLocale: function() {
                console.log("es");
                i18n.locale = "es";
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**main.js**

```js
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import {routes} from './routes.js';
import {messages} from './i18n.js';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueI18n);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <navbar></navbar>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <footer-part></footer-part>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Navbar from './components/site/Navbar.vue';
    import Footer from './components/site/Footer.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            'navbar' : Navbar,
            'footer-part' : Footer
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should prefix it using `$` sign and `this` keyword :

```
   this.$i18n.locale = "es";
```